# How to connect with a .sql database (stored in a local folder)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a database.sql file stored in my folder (which contains some tables named like pro, id ecc..). i just want to connect with it in order to do some query using sqlite library. Here the code and the error i got.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\lucai\\Desktop\\python\\database.sql")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select count(distinct pro_id) from pro")
```

the error i got is this: `DatabaseError: file is not a database`

Any suggestions?

Comment: That file isn't a sqlite database.... Um. Are you trying to open a text file full of SQL statements?

Comment: i don't know what's inside the file, i'm just trying to connect to this .sql file i have. i can' open it and i can't know what's inside

Comment: i open the .sql file and it is a big list of sql code (create table from ecc...)

Comment: how do i can make it work in python? (if possible)

Comment: You'd have to import it into a sqlite database (using the `sqlite3` command line she'll or whatever other tool you prefer). Then you can open the populated database.

Comment: @Shawn can you share one example please? my code i used is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your .sql file as you described in the comments, is not a database.
In your case is a list of SQL commands.

Comment: i now reached to connect with the mysql database, now there's a new issue. I wish to know how to tranform data from this connection to a pandas dataframe.